# django registration redux URL's being effected by url with multiple query parameters

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls, django-registration

My Url's supplied by django registration redux don't work when the following url is used:

```
url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.project_page, name='user_project'),
```

but then they do work if I add another level to that url like this:

```
url(r'^projects/(?P<username>\w+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.project_page, name='user_project'),
```

I don't want to add that extra project/ url level in there if possible. Why would it be effecting the django registration redux url's and how can I fix it? Any help would be much appreciated :-)

project urls

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from registration.backends.simple.views import RegistrationView

class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):  #redirects to home page after registration
    def get_success_url(self,request, user):
        return '/register_profile'

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('howdidu.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'), #redirects to home page after registration
    (r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),

)

# media
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
        'django.views.static',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)',
        'serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), )
```

app urls

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from howdidu import views
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^register_profile/$', views.register_profile, name='register_profile'),
        url(r'^update_profile/$', views.update_profile, name='update_profile'),
        url(r'^create_project/$', login_required(views.CreateProject.as_view()), name='create_project'),
        url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.profile_page, name='user_profile'),
        url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.project_page, name='user_project'),
        )
```

Comment: When you say that it's not working, please also post what is the issue. Post the error if you got any. That will save us from running your code.

Comment: BTW, I guess you meant *regex* when you say *redux*?

Comment: Hi, it is django registration redux which is a registration app. When I click any link to do with that app, such as register, login or logout it will try and load to url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.project_page, name='user_project'), but the url in the browser is http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/logout/?next=/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your url ordering, take a look at this:

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'', include('howdidu.urls')),
url(r'^accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'), #redirects to home page after registration
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
```

Especially this:

```
url(r'', include('howdidu.urls')),
```

this url matches everything, so basically Django will go from the top to the bottom and if it doesn't find any match before `url(r'', include('howdidu.urls'))`, it will match anything to it. This means that you will never match

```
url(r'^accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'), #redirects to home page after registration
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
```

One way to fix it is to place `url(r'', include('howdidu.urls'))` at the very bottom of the urls:

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'), #redirects to home page after registration
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
url(r'^', include('howdidu.urls')),
```

and another way is to set another url level for `url(r'^', include('howdidu.urls'))`:

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^howdidu/', include('howdidu.urls')),
url(r'^accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'), #redirects to home page after registration
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
```

Comment: Thanks again @pythad!! I went with your first fix of moving the url(r'', include('howdidu.urls') to the bottom and it worked :-). You are a star!